# Verilog bit shift

Tags: verilog

I'm just starting out on how to learn verilog and I stumbled upon this problem. So  I'm trying to make a bit shifter that shifts the input bit once to the left for each rising clock pulse. However, when I tried running the simulations, the output came out as XXXX. Any help will be apreciated

```
module shift_left #(parameter i=3)(
input clk,
input rst,
input [i:0]data_in,
output reg [i:0]data_out
);
wire [i:0]in;
assign in=data_in;
reg [i:0]temp;

always @(posedge clk)begin

    if(rst==1)begin
        temp<=in;
    end
    else
        data_out<=temp;
        temp<=temp<<1;
        temp[0]=1'b0;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: You follow a non-blocking assignment immediately with a blocking assignment. I suspect that might be related to your issue. As an aside, what is the benefit of `assign in=data_in`? Since it's a `wire` and not a `reg` (which you would assign to in the `always @` block), I don't think it changes anything if you were to use `temp<=data_in` instead under `rst==1` condition.

Comment: you need to provide a snipped of your test bench code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a synchronous `reset` and your issue is mostly due to not asserting the `reset` in your TB at the start of the simulation. You need to follow at least 1 assertion-deassertion sequence with your `reset` signal before you proceed with the rest of your simulation.

As for your code, as Patrick pointed out, you dont need to create that extra `wire [i:0] in`. You can directly do `temp <= data_in` in your `always` block.

Also, there is no need to do `temp[0] = 1'b0;` because the left shift operator `<<` will automatically take care of inserting a zero to the LSB.

A word of advice : do not mix blocking and non-blocking statements within the same `always` block, at least not when you are just beginning to learn Verilog